# Как называется выпуклый (рельефный) рисунок/урашение на предмете?

Tags: выбор-слова

[Барельеф](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B5%D1%84), мне кажется, это больше из архитетуры, про стакан так не скажешь. А есть ли слово, которое описывает подобные украшения на предметах?

[image]

Comment: Так это рельеф и есть. Рельеф или рельефное изображение, вы же сами это так называете.

Answer (score 2):

Самый точный из известных мне терминов - это "рельефная резьба". 
Иногда сами такие изделия называют резными, но тут специалисты пусть меня поправят - мне кажется резным может быть что-то не обязательно рельефное.

[image]

Если быть ещё чуть точнее, рельефная резьба как-раз [делится на](https://proekt-sam.ru/rezba/relyefnaya-rezba-po-derevu.html) так называемую глухорельефную и плоскорельефную, последняя как раз делится на барельефную и горельефную. Но вы правы, барельефом это всё-таки (в обиходной речи) не называют.

Comment: Стакан - металлический. Очень сомнительно, что это резьба, скорее это отлив.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh тогда это рельефная гравировка!

Answer (score 2):

Выпуклый рисунок - горельеф или барельеф. Если выступает меньше, чем на половину объёма частей, то барельеф, если больше - горельеф.

Answer (score 0):

Также это может быть инкрустация (если не вырезано из объекта подложки) https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F